# Authorized XMLHttpRequest in VBA for Excel

Tags: sharepoint, excel, vba

I want to perform a post request in vba on a sharepoint, but i get answer 401 Unauthorized.
Could someone provide me some sample code?

Thx for help.

Comment: That is not usually the way it works. Perhaps you could post your problem code?

Comment: How is access to the Sharepoint site controlled ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a proxy issue.  Which is a major pain in the ass.  You could automate an internet explorer window in the background, worst case.  Have you heard of fiddler? You can use that to make sure you're including all the right headers.  As far as I know, XMLHttpRequest in VBA doesn't hold cookies, which you may need as well.